# XCelsius using ZOHO webservice

Tags: web-services, zoho, xcelsius

I need to make a dashboard application using data from http://www.projects.zoho.com
It is a project management site.

ZOHO provides data about projects by APIs available at http://www.zoho.com/projects/developers/projects-api.html

So can I use XCelsius engage to make my dashboard?
Is it feasible & advisable?

Also tell me if any other tool like XCelsius is more suitable for me....

expecting satisfactory answers....

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem as long as the results returned via XML aren't too complex. Unfortunately Xcelsius has a hard time dealing with nested XML tags of more than a few levels so it is best to ensure that you try to conform data to a  table structure. Taking this into consideration depending on complexity you may or may not have to massage data received from ZOHO prior to loading it into Xcelsius.

You also need to be mindful of [flash domain security practices](http://myxcelsius.com/2008/11/18/straight-from-xcelsius-best-practices-flash-security/) if you are not already aware of them.